# add new line in gridview cell

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a gridview that [display grade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTRH8.png), but i don't want to display in one line. What i have tried is like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN0lm.png) it became wrap text.
the code

```
     gridView_Attendees.Columns["grade"].Caption = "Grade";
     gridView_Attendees.Columns["grade"].Width = 150;
     gridView_Attendees.Columns["grade"].OptionsFilter.AutoFilterCondition = AutoFilterCondition.Contains;
     gridView_Attendees.OptionsView.RowAutoHeight = true;
     gridView_Attendees.Columns["grade"].AppearanceCell.TextOptions.WordWrap = WordWrap.Wrap;
     RepositoryItemMemoEdit memoEdit = new RepositoryItemMemoEdit();
     memoEdit.ReadOnly = true;
     memoEdit.AutoHeight = true;
     memoEdit.WordWrap = true;
     gridView_Attendees.GridControl.RepositoryItems.Add(memoEdit);
     gridView_Attendees.Columns["grade"].ColumnEdit = memoEdit;
```

what i want is add new line to break into 2 lines, precisely before text `Technique`. like this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgKgq.png)

Comment: Does the value in the Grade property of your grid's datasource contain a newline character before 'Technique'?

Comment: nope, its all in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To achieve your goal, assign MemoEdit editor as a cell in-place editor
>   and set the View's OptionsView.RowAutoHeight property to True.

You have already used this approach but it does not work as you want so you can emulate the desired behavior by handling the [GridView.CustomDrawCell event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic): draw the multi-line text and set the e.Handled property to true to prevent the default painting of the grid's cell's content. In this case, you need to increase the grid's row height. To do it, set the [GridView.RowHeight](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowHeighttopic) property or handle the [GridView.CalcRowHeight](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CalcRowHeighttopic) event , to set the individual height for the every grid's row (in this case, the GridView.OptionsView.RowAutoHeight property should be set to false).

References:
[Display multi-line text in gridview cell](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T448080/display-multi-line-text-in-gridview-cell)
[Multi line text indentation in XtraGrid memoedit cell](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q257544/multi-line-text-indentation-in-xtragrid-memoedit-cell)
[gridview cell display multiline text](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q260307/gridview-cell-display-multiline-text)